# After an AJAX action to create, how do you send back an updated collection of objects in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I am confused about how to send back an updated collection of @tasks after the create action so that I can see the newly created item on the page without having to do a refresh. How do I do this? Let me walk you through my code in order.

First, here is my index.html.erb code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
    <h2>Tasks</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4">
    <%= link_to new_task_path, remote: true do %>
      <button class="btn btn-default">New</button>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2" id="task-form" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1" id="tasks"><%= render @tasks %></div>
</div>
```

I will click on the "New" button which hits the new action of the controller.  Here is my controller code:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :all_tasks, only: [:create, :update]
  before_action :set_tasks, only: [:edit, :update]

  respond_to :html, :js

  # index action has been removed
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json
    end
  end

  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  def create
    @task  = Task.create(task_params)
  end

  def update
    @task.update_attributes(task_params)
  end

  private

  def all_tasks
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  def set_tasks
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:description, :deadline)
  end
end
```

This will render the new.js.erb code:

```
$('#task-form').html("<%= j (render 'form') %>");
$('#task-form').slideDown(350);
```

This will render the new form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @task, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.input :deadline %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I hit submit, it will hit the create action of the controller again

```
def create
    @task  = Task.create(task_params)
  end
```

After here, what I would like to do is send back an updated collection of @tasks and render them on the page. Is there anyway I can just render the index.html.erb view again and send it Task.all?

Answer (score 0):

Add instance variable `@tasks` in your `def create`

```
def create
  @task  = Task.create(task_params)
  @tasks = Task.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Create a new file `create.js.erb`

```
$('#tasks').html("<%= j (render @tasks) %>");
```

Comment: does rails automatically look for a create.js.erb file? How does it do this?

Comment: also what does render @tasks do for you behind the scenes?

Comment: Yes, it is. Rails will use `create.js.erb` as respond js format in `create` method. In behind the scenes of render @tasks, I'm not sure about this but rails can do automatically to detect the file and objects. Can you tell me about what file do you use in render partial @tasks?

Answer (score 0):

In your case your `create.js.erb` will be something like this:

```
$('#tasks').append("<li> <%= @task.inspect %> </li>");
```